# With GZIP, Can I write 'Sloppy' CSS (and other type of code) code?

Tags: css, performance, gzip

The drumbeat of writing terse CSS code has been beaten into my head for years. For example:

Do this:
    .foo,.bar{
    color:#f00;
    }

Not this:
    .foo{
    color:#f00;
    }
    .bar{
      color:#f00;
    }

With GZIP compression isn't it irrelevant how I write the above CSS? Since GZIP will create a dynamic library with color:#f00 as a single instance and use pointers to its multiple uses. I want to know because it is more convenient to repeat style definitions versus searching for an identical declaration.

Comment: Wouldn't writing the CSS correctly take up less space than the gzipped incorrect css? Or did I miss the point?

Comment: @EvilChookie: a gzipped CSS will be generally smaller than a similar bloated CSS.

Comment: One consideration is this:  Are you writing sloppy code just because you don't have to write it well?  That thinking can lead you into a world of crap code that is a nightmare for you later and your successor on any project, as well as poor performance.  I don't think you are because you are asking... guys like that don't care and are lazy regardless, I just wanted to make the point because one of my pet peeves is Hello World that takes almost 20K because of "Every machine has at least 1GB of memory and I don't have to write it well!" thinking :)

Comment: I think this question missed my point. I am not so interested in the merits of good CSS code (as I have my dogmatic beliefs about CSS) rather investigating whether GZIP, by creating a dynamic library of words as it builds it zip file, usurps 'optimization' techniques. If so, then I do not have to 'make the effort' of finding identical definitions and can write duplicates because GZIP takes a single instance of a word and uses pointers for the other duplicates. There , from a HTTP download point-of-view, duplicates are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you try to achieve:

- If .foo and .bar need to have the same colour, you´re better of using the first method because it is easier to maintain.
- If your first statement is a result of you manually optimizing your file-size, and it´s just a coincidence that .foo and .bar have the same properties, I would definitely split it and use the second solution.

In the end gzip and / or a css compressor will handle the file size so I wouldn´t worry about that.

Worry about maintainability and readability instead.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [css minifier](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&hs=xNW&ei=XX7GSoCVB5XKtgeA75XuDg&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=css+minifier&spell=1) before publishing and stop worrying about readability and file size.

GZIP will definitely have a bigger before/after size impact with 'sloppy' CSS files, but having the smallest file possible before compression, is <del>always</del>most of the time a good thing<sup>tm</sup>, as it will be marginally smaller.

---

Remember: *Source code is for humans to read, and only incidentally for machines to run.*

Comment: Good quote. I say we let compressors do nasty hacks for us and let our production code shrink as compressors improve. :)

Answer (score 2):

If that makes sense, go for it. Otherwise, I'd write the CSS in a logical fashion so it can be maintained properly, and then rely on gzip + a CSS compressor (like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)) to handle the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would still want to continue using the first method because it's more readable.  Having a separate section for every thing will make you css bloated and difficult for people to get through it.

Comment: Not if the two classes aren't related in any way, or it's likely that individual definitions will change and separate out over time.

Comment: @iftrue I'm assuming they're related, otherwise why would they be grouped in the first place.  Also, I wouldn't separate something out because it was "likely" that it would need separation in the future.  If the future dictates separation, then let it happen when it happens, don't try to predict what you don't know.